# R: Split a string into new row and column

Tags: r

input:

```
tmp <- "(12,'chinese'),(13,'italian'),(14,'spanish')"
```

desired output:

```
id   food_type
12    chinese
13    italian
14    spanish
```

I tried gsub/string split but realized that feeding into new row and column is another problem. thanks

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? Which programming/scripting language are you attempting to write the solution in? And am I to assume that tmp is the name of a file that hold the data that you wish to process and you want to pass that file to the program/script?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution based on `eval(parse(text = ))` by convert the string into an expression:

```
x <- eval(parse(text = paste0('list(', gsub('\\(', 'c\\(', tmp), ')')))

res <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(res) <- c('id', 'food_type')

res
#   id food_type
# 1 12   chinese
# 2 13   italian
# 3 14   spanish
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `strsplit` and `sub`:

```
tmp <- "(12,'chinese'),(13,'italian'),(14,'spanish')"
terms <- strsplit(tmp, "(?<=\\)),(?=\\()", perl=TRUE)
df <- lapply(terms[[1]], function(x) {
    id <- sub("^\\(([^,]*).*", "\\1", x)
    food_type <- sub(".*,'(.*)'\\)", "\\1", x)
    z <- c(id, food_type)
    return(z)
})
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df)
names(df) <- c("id", "food_type")
df

  id food_type
1 12   chinese
2 13   italian
3 14   spanish
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Hey checkout this solution i hope it will help you.

```
tmp1=gsub("\\'","",gsub("\\(","",unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(tmp,",")),"\\)"))))
id=as.numeric(tmp1[seq(1,length(tmp2),2)])
fooditem=tmp1[seq(0,length(tmp2),2)]
res=data.frame(id,fooditem)

  id fooditem
1 12  chinese
2 13  italian
3 14  spanish
```

Comment: Please accept the solution if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to change the `input` and use `read.table` function to get the desired output. The final steps turned out to be:

```
df <- lapply(strsplit(tmp, "\\(|\\)\\,?", perl = TRUE), function(x){
  x <- x[x != ""]
  read.table(text = paste0(x), sep = ",", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})
df <- do.call(rbind, df)
names(df) <- c("id", "food_type")
# Result:
#> df
#  id food_type
#1 12   chinese
#2 13   italian
#3 14   spanish
```